# While creating Mean.io Project I get the error

Tags: node.js, git, mean-stack

```
C:\Users\Kashif\Desktop\Mean-io>mean init myAPp
? What would you name your mean app? myAPp
On windows platform - Please check permissions independently
All permissions should be run with the local users permissions
Cloning branch: master into destination folder: myAPp
git clone  --depth 1  -bmaster https://github.com/linnovate/mean.git "myAPp"
FIND: Parameter format not correct
There are 2 files in your ~/.npm owned by root
Please change the permissions by running - chown -R `whoami` ~/.npm

C:\Users\Kashif\AppData\Roaming\npm\node_modules\mean-cli\lib\utils.js:67
      throw('ROOT PERMISSIONS IN NPM');
      ^
ROOT PERMISSIONS IN NPM
```

I also tried with ROOT access but the error is same.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem today, and I've found out that **utils.js** uses the following command to find files owned by the root:

```
var findCmd = 'find ' + homeDir +'/.npm ' + '-user root';
```

which obviously doesn't work on Windows.

A work around for this is to make sure that you have the right permission on the directory and comment out `shell.exec()`.

Cheers.